# File writing function isn't writing the correct information in PHP

Tags: php, function, csv, fopen

I have 2 scripts one containing a function that writes a .csv file, and the other that calls the function.

The file writing function.

```
<?php
include("config.php");

function exportMysqlToCsv($subid){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM campaigns"; 
$results = mysql_query($sql);
$getpub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `publishers` WHERE `username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$pinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getpub);

// Pick a filename and destination directory for the file 
// Remember that the folder where you want to write the file has to be writable 
$filename = "campaigns_export_pub".$pinfo['id'].".csv"; 

// Actually create the file 
// The w+ parameter will wipe out and overwrite any existing file with the same name 
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+'); 

// Write the spreadsheet column titles / labels 
fputcsv($handle, array('Campaign ID','Campaign Name','Promoting URL','Category','Rate','Countries','Description','Requirements')); 

// Write all the user records to the spreadsheet 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{ 
$url = "http://www.rageleads.com/click.php?aid=".$pinfo['id']."&cid=".$row['id']."&sid=".$subid."";
    fputcsv($handle, array($row['id'], $row['name'], $url, $row['category'], $row['rate'], $row['countries'], $row['description'], $row['requirements'])); 
} 

// Finish writing the file 
fclose($handle); 

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename");
readfile($filename);
unlink($filename);
exit();
}
?>
```

The function call.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
include("header.php");
include("functions.php");
include("export.php");

$subid = cleanQuery($_POST['subid']);

if($_POST['submit']){
exportMysqlToCsv($subid);
}

print"
<div id='center'>
<table class='balances'>
<form method='POST' action=''>
<tr>
<td>Sub ID Placeholder:</td>
<td><input type='text' name='subid' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Export' /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>";

include("footer.php");
?>
```

The problem I am having is instead of writing the .csv file the way it is defined in the function it is writing the actual html code of the page in which the function call is on and then adding the information that is defined in the function. This is the first time I have ever written a file writing function so I am sure I have messed something up somewhere, but I am not quite sure what I have done wrong.

If I have export.php set up as not being a function and simply go the the page it writes and downloads the csv file in the correct format in which it is defined to do.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I don't know why I didn't do it before but when I check the csv file that it creates on my server everything is right, so something in the headers is sending this extra information, but I don't know which one, or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.  If you send the CSV data, make sure it is the only thing you are sending.  Otherwise, send the HTML file.  You were explicitly sending both the HTML AND the CSV.

```
$subid = cleanQuery($_POST['subid']);
if($_POST['submit']) {
    exportMysqlToCsv($subid);
} else {
    include("config.php");
    include("header.php");
    include("functions.php");
    include("export.php");

    print"
    <div id='center'>
    <table class='balances'>
    <form method='POST' action=''>
    <tr>
    <td>Sub ID Placeholder:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='subid' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Export' /></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </div>";

    include("footer.php");
}
```

Comment: I should have thought of this to begin with, thank you so much the csv file is passing the correct information now!